# Mac OS Hosts file change doesn't get picked up by the application for the keyword 'issuer"

Tags: linux, macos, dns, hosting, hosts

My team member told me to change host file in order to be picked up by the application to be accessed to certain page of the application.

For example, there are two urls for the application.
broker.blabla.com/1234/detail
issuer.blabla.com/1234/detail

so I tried changing my host file on mac to these, and then tried to go on 
http://issuer.blabla.com/0xD1791c/detail
but it says

```
This site can’t be reached
issuer.blabla.com refused to connect.

sudo nano /private/etc/hosts
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder

##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost issuer.blabla.com
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       issuer.blalbla.com
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

this is the original host file before changing.

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

Am I doing something wrong?

My teammate explained we are just mimicking different urls in local environment.